# ¿Por qué no me permite almacenar un fichero binario en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, netbeans

Buenas, soy nuevo en Java, y no entiendo el por qué del error que me devuelve la consola de Netbeans.

Lo que trato de hacer es crear un fichero binario con dos objetos de la clase Usuario, que de hecho, hasta aquí todo va perfecto.

Más tarde deseo leer el contenido del fichero almancenándolo en un ArrayList para leerlo después con más calma, pero es ahí donde salta el error y no me deja continuar.

El error concreto que me devuelve es el siguiente:

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: clases.Usuario cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at mt1.Mt1.main(Mt1.java:44) ***

Esta es la línea en la que aparece:

***ArrayList  au = (ArrayList ) leer.readObject();***

No entiendo el error ya que la clase es Serializable y estoy casteando correctamente creo la lectura del objeto.

Os dejo ambos códigos a continuación, tanto el del Main como el de la clase Usuario, ya que no tengo ni idea de dónde esta el fallo. Cualquier ayuda será bienvenida. Gracias por adelantado :)

***Archivo del Main***

```
package mt1;

import clases.Usuario;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Mt1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Usuario nuevo = new Usuario("campo1","campo2","campo3");
            Usuario nuevo2 = new Usuario("campo1","campo2","campo3");
            String nombre = "mat.dat";

        FileOutputStream ins = null;
        try {
            ins = new FileOutputStream(nombre);
            ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(ins);
            escribir.writeObject(nuevo);
            escribir.writeObject(nuevo2);
            escribir.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                ins.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        FileInputStream ins2 = null;
        try {
            ins2 = new FileInputStream(nombre);
            ObjectInputStream leer = new ObjectInputStream(ins2);
            ArrayList <Usuario> au = (ArrayList <Usuario>) leer.readObject();
            leer.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) { // El EOFException va metido aquí y sale siempre. 
            Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }

}
```

*** Clase Usuario ***

```
package clases;

public class Usuario implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String nom;
    private String pass;
    private String id;

    public Usuario(String nom, String pass, String id) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.pass = pass;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Usuario{" + "nom=" + nom + ", pass=" + pass + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, no estás casteando correctamente la lectura del objeto.

Has almacenado objetos de tipo `Usuario` en el fichero. Por lo tanto, para leer correctamente estos objetos los debes castear a su tipo, que es `Usuario`.

Ejemplo:

```
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) leer.readObject();
```

Si lo que deseas es leer todos los `Usuarios` almacenados en el fichero y guardarlos en un `ArrayList` debes realizar las siguientes acciones:

1. Crear una instancia nueva de `ArrayList`.
2. Recorrer todos los objetos `Usuario` del fichero.
3. Para cada objeto `Usuario`, añadirlo en el `ArrayList`.

Por ejemplo:

```
List<Usuario> listUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
Usuario usuario = null;
do {
    usuario = (Usuario) leer.readObject();
    if(usuario != null){
        listUsuarios.add(usuario);
    } 
} while (usuario != null)
```

(No olvides cerrar el `InputStream`, preferiblemente en un bloque `finally`)

También tienes otra alternativa, que puede simplificar tu código y es la de escribir en el fichero directamente un `ArrayList` con los usuarios. De este modo la lectura del fichero que planteas, sería correcta.

Por ejemplo, para escribir en el fichero:

```
List<Usuario> listUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
listUsuarios.add(nuevo);
listUsuarios.add(nuevo2);

try {
    ins = new FileOutputStream(nombre);
    ObjectOutputStream escribir = new ObjectOutputStream(ins);
    escribir.writeObject(listUsuarios);

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} finally {
    try {
        ins.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Mt1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Para leer:

```
List <Usuario> au = (List <Usuario>) leer.readObject();
```